# Retrieving objects between classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I always get tied up with small things like this... I need to access an objects properties created in class 'Login' from my welcome page class 'Default'. When I try to reference the class so that I may access the object, VS 2010 doesn't list it as available like it normally would, and forcing the request just returns an error.

My `Login` Class is defined like so:

```
public abstract class Login : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   ...
   private void Login_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
      myObject.property1 = "something";
   }
}
```

And then i wish to access `myObject` from my default class, like this:

```
public class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   ...   
   private void Page_load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
      string someLocalVar = Login.myObject.property1;
   }
}
```

Where `property1` is a property set in the Login class. This does not work, however, and VS doesn't even recognize the Login class; instead it treats it as a reserved word of some sort. These two files are in the same project, so that shouldn't be an issue in the `using` section. I've accessed variables in this manner between other classes before, just not this time for some reason.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things:

- Your class is `abstract`
- Your property is probably not `static`
- You don't actually have a property, it's a local variable

You can't instantiate an instance of an `abstract` class. The point of an `abstract` class is to create a class with some shared code that other, similar child classes can inherit. Is there a reason your class is abstract?

If your property is not `static` you have to create an instance of your class in order to access the property. (Which, as I describe above, you can't because it's abstract). If you make your property static, you could then do `Login.MyObject` without creating an instance.

In the code you supplied, your variable is local to the `Login_click` method, which means even if you created an instance of your class you wouldn't be able to access it.

**I suggest you pick up a C# book and read up on the fundamentals.**

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of issues here. First, you're accessing `myObject` like it's a member of `Login`, which it isn't. It's a local variable to your `Login_click` method. Second, you never create an instance of `Login` in your `Default` class, so unless it's a static class or you actually create an instance of it, you're not going to be able to access any members of it.

Here's something more like what you want (I think). I've left out your class inheritance for now.

```
public class Login 
{
    MyObject object;

    public Login() {
        object = new MyObject();
        object.property1 = "something";
    }
}

public class Default {
    private void Login_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Login _login = new Login();
        string someLocalVar = _login.object.property1; 
    }
}
```

Like others have said, you need to more carefully plan this out and strengthen your programming skills before attempting this. This is basic stuff so it shouldn't take an exorbitant amount of time -- don't worry though, we all started here.

Comment: is there a way to create a sort of global object that is accessible throughout the project?

Comment: @Nibirue Well, yes. It's called a public class. I'm not sure you're handling basic programming principles here. I'm not trying to be offensive, but you need to learn to walk before you can run.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your object into a `Session` variable, and then Cast it back.

```
//in Login.aspx
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.property1 = "something";
Session["UserObject"] = myObject;

//in default.aspx
MyObject obj = (MyObject)Session["UserObject"]
string variable = obj.property1;
```

Comment: @MohammedElSayed ah, its alright. Thanks for removing the Downvote :-)

Comment: This his hack-y at best in this scenario. I think OP needs a better grasp at basic programming principles before he dives in to something like this.

Comment: it would be more appropriate for `myObject` to be a property of the Login class.

Comment: But I don't understand the downvote. It will be helpful to others who visit this page later in time.

Comment: the downvote indicates that this answer is suboptimal.  No offense is meant, but this solution sucks.  It violates basic programming principles and is not terribly maintainable.  Dont worry about down votes.. just means you have more to learn (as do we all!)

Comment: @Dan-o this is one of the _legal_ ways of object passing between two pages.

Comment: @Aniket You're not wrong, but that doesn't make it a good idea in this scenario.

Comment: In addition Aniket's comment: Login is a `UserControl`, not a `Page`